# Liquibase - Generate diff changelog between real and test database in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase, testcontainers

I'm working on adding integration tests to an existing Spring Boot project, and for that we have a test db on a docker container (initialized before running the tests).

Since the development db may change from time to time (new tables, views, etc...) the test db should have the same structure for obvious reasons. I'm recreating the test db using a Liquibase changelog generated with the generateChangeLog command (manually).

So, what i'm thinking of is to generate a diff changelog between the development db and the test db and apply the necessary changes to the test db before running the tests, but i haven't found any information from liquibase regarding these kinds of procedures. Are the diff changelogs always created manually?

What would be the best way to do this? I'm thinking on creating a method to run the diff-changelog command and update the test db right before running the tests, and therefore "automating" the procedure.